# Canadian to US English

Tags: list, dictionary, nlp

Does there exist something like Canadian to US English e-dictionary which I can use in my application?

Comment: Do you just need translations for a few particular words?

Comment: I think he wants a full translator for all the words, is how I take it. Since the only difference is the spelling (I think?) there's no need for grammar really. All he needs is a full word list I guess and he could write the translator himself.

Comment: What's the US equivalent of Canadian bacon?

Comment: I can think of only a few:  Eh? == Huh?,  Eh! == Cool!  The rest are pronunciation.

Comment: yaeh I need a full translator for all the words

Comment: @Crises of Identity: I believe you call it Peameal bacon there. To be honest so do I, and I call American bacon (the real bacon)..bacon.

I love bacon.

Comment: As Winston Churchill said, 'Two nations, divided by the use of a common language.' But he was talking about the US and UK

Comment: @random Canadian bacon is what Americans call it. Canadians call it peameal or back bacon. The default "bacon" is the same food in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy Ruby function which will work 90% of the time for [Canadian English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian%5FEnglish#Spelling_and_dictionaries).

```
def toCanadian(american)
  american.gsub(/or$/, 'our').gsub(/er$/, 're') + " eh?"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any such dictionaries exist as a usable module. However I did find on the Ubuntu wiki a very complete looking list between en-US and en-GB (British):
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EnglishTranslation/WordSubstitution

And if you go here it has some links to different resources:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EnglishTranslation

One of which is here: http://www3.telus.net/linguisticsissues/britishcanadianamericanvocaba.html

I think it's the type of thing you might have to do manually, although that's just from browsing Google briefly. Perhaps someone has already done something like this and has or knows of something that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I thought Canadians spoke English and French... :)

What programming language?

There's the [Google Ajax Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) for web apps...

Answer (score 0):

There are some hints in the [Wikipedia article *Canadian English*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English#Spelling_and_dictionaries), such as *lor = *lour.  Combine that with some of the American English encyclopedias [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824422/can-i-get-an-english-dictionary-word-list-somewhere).

Comment: neighbour. Also the doubling of l in marshalling, traveller etc - though I work in both languages so much I tend to forget which does which.